# Add Array of Objects into UseState ([])

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, firebase, object

i´m getting following error message ***"Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {fzfvhv76576, user }). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."*** Im trying to add my firebase data into an Array of UseState([]). I tried several methods, but unfortunately without success, i have no ideas anymore. Hope someone can help me.

```
export function ListUserTask() {
  
    const [tasks, getUserTasks] = useState([] as any);
    var data: Object[] = [];

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const userData = await getUserTask();

            console.log("userData", userData);
           
            for (let index = 0; index < userData.length; index++) {
                console.log("loop", data);
                
                data.push(userData[index]);
                getUserTasks([tasks, data[index]]);
                // console.log("useState:", tasks);
            }
        })();
    }, []);

    return (
        <IonContent>
            <IonText color="muted">
                <h2>Get User Tasks</h2>
                <h2>{tasks}</h2>
            </IonText>
        </IonContent>
    );
}

export default ListUserTask;
```

my Firebase structure as followed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to render an entire object in the h2 tag which is wrong in React.

```
<IonContent>
        <IonText color="muted">
            <h2>Get User Tasks</h2>
            <h2>{tasks}</h2>  // WRONG
        </IonText>
    </IonContent>
```

I will try to update your code:

```
export function ListUserTask() {

const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([] as any);

useEffect(async () => {
   const userData = await getUserTask();
   if(userData){
     setTasks(userData);
     }
}, []);

return (
    <IonContent>
        <IonText color="muted">
            <h2>Get User Tasks</h2>
            {tasks.map(t) => <h2>{t.user}</h2>}
           
        </IonText>
    </IonContent>
    );
}

export default ListUserTask;
```